# geoserver and openlayers select rectangle pixel values

Tags: openlayers, raster, geoserver, geotiff

I'm running a geoserver (2.5.x) with 1 raster file (GeoTIFF) as a layer. From my application I can access a single pixel value when clicked (through WMS), but what I'm really interested in is to get a range of pixels and then do some processing on that. The way I was thinking of doing it was to create a control with MOD_CTRL as trigger and then when dragging ended, to pass the selected range to geoserver so that I can get a list of pixel values back.

```
    OpenLayers.Util.extend(control, {
      draw: function () {
          this.drag = new OpenLayers.Handler.Box( control,
              {"done": this.notice},
              {keyMask: OpenLayers.Handler.MOD_CTRL});
          this.drag.activate();
      },

      notice: function (bounds) {
        leftBottom = map.getLonLatFromPixel(new OpenLayers.Pixel(bounds.left, bounds.bottom)); 
        rightTop = map.getLonLatFromPixel(new OpenLayers.Pixel(bounds.right, bounds.top));
        console.log(leftBottom, rightTop);
        return(true);
      }
```

The problem I'm facing is that I can't seem to find a way to pass the "range" (leftBottom,rightTop) to the geoserver - only a single pixel. The leftBottom and rightTop works fine, but how do I get back the list of pixel values?

This function seems to make the call but I'm not sure which service or parameters to use...

```
 function makeCall(bounds) {

   var url = sec.getFullRequestString({
                                          REQUEST: "GetFeature",
                                          SERVICE: "WFS", //should this be WPS?
                                          EXCEPTIONS: "application/vnd.ogc.se_xml",
                                          typeNames: 'mystore:mylayer',
                                          BBOX: bounds.toBBOX(),
                                          INFO_FORMAT: 'text/plain',
                                          QUERY_LAYERS: layerlist,
                                          FEATURE_COUNT: 50,
                                          WIDTH: map.size.w,
                                          HEIGHT: map.size.h,
                                          format: 'image/png',
                                        },
                                        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs");

    var request = OpenLayers.Request.GET({
      url: url,
      callback: extractFeatures
    });
  }
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

WMS has no way to get a rectangular range of pixels, you need to use WCS, or eventually a custom WPS process.